# How to get a confidence interval for each parameter in an stochastic optimization problem?

Tags: confidence-interval, optimization, identifiability, stochastic-approximation

I'm using Differential Evolution to locate the global minimum in a search space with the objective function being the Root Mean Squared Error. I'm using a mathematical model with number of parameters $\vec{V} = [V_0, V_1, .., V_{n}]$ and fitting these parameters to experimental data. The issue is I'm trying to find a way to quantify confidence in a given solution by specifying confidence intervals for each parameter, but I am not sure where to begin with this.

My objective function is the RMSE:  $$f(\vec{V}_{solution}) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} (Z_{exp} - Z_{cal}(\vec{V}_{solution}))^2 }$$

I've looked at how confidence intervals are calculated in least-squares methods and it seems one needs to know or assume what distribution is followed by the population. For example I tried the standard way confidence intervals are calculated using the variance of the population and Student's $t$ distribution for a given confidence level $c = 0.95$ for example:
$$\left[M - \frac{\sigma^2 t_c}{\sqrt{n - 1}}, M + \frac{\sigma^2 t_c}{\sqrt{n - 1}}\right]$$
This makes sense if we're looking for a confidence interval around a population *mean* M, but in my case I'm looking for a confidence interval around the minimum that was found differential evolution, which is unlikely to be the mean of the population.

I'm not much of a statistician and I realize this might not be a well-posed problem at all since I'm using a non-deterministic method with a non-differentiable objective function, so I don't know how such a thing could be done for this kind of evolutionary algorithm, but a push to the right direction would help.